# Rails has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :basiccases
end

class Basiccase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :form3_c
end

class Form3C < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :basiccases
end
```

How can I add a new `Form3C` to the `Basiccase`? Do I need to use a `Basiccase` controller or `Form3C` controller to create a form? If I use `Form3cController` how can I set the foreign key in the `BasiccaseController?`

Comment: The `has_one` relation should go into a model, not a controller. So if you have a `Form3C` model class, try to add there the relation. The `has_one` relation should go to singular as in `has_one :basiccase`. You would normally build the `Basiccase` from the `Form3C` instance: `self.build_basiccase` will build the  basiccase that `belongs_to` `Form3C`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relationships like `has_one` are defined on models rather than controllers. I think you want this (to be able to add a `Form3c` to a `Basiccase`--not sure which direction you want the relationship to go):

```
class Form3c < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :basiccase
end

class Basiccase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :form3c
end
```

For tips on building the controller and form (view), look at [this Rails tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), starting around section 6.

Comment: I'm really confused where to keep the has_one relation as both are one to one. My requirement is user should be able to add new form to a basic case.Can you suggest me how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Though your naming of model is not that convincing, I am assuming your `basiccases` table has one column `form3c_id`.

You need to create a form for `form3c` object then in controller you can build a `basiccase` object like `@form3c_build_basiccase` which will automatically take `form3c_id` as a foreign key. Refer to [this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1).

Or you may go for `form3c` model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :basiccase`. See about it [here](http://rubysource.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/).